# How to shorten the Windows RPC call timeout?

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, rpc, idl

When I try to call a RPC function, which generated from an IDL file by midl tool, it blocks around 20 seconds (at the NdrGetBuffer function) if the IP bound in its RPC_BINDING_HANDLE is unreachable.

I tried to call RpcMgmtSetComTimeout function with RPC_C_BINDING_MIN_TIMEOUT value on its RPC_BINDING_HANDLE before calling that RPC function, but no help, still need to wait ~20 seconds.

Is there any way to shorten the timeout wait time on this case? Thanks a lot!

Elliott

Comment: Well, in general, it takes a long time to find out that a host is really unreachable. The internet is quite big, and has all sorts of links, with varying latency.  What I do when faced with possibly very-long network delays is to thread off the network call and also run a timer. Either the remote peer replies before the timer fires.. or it does not and I consider the call failed.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yes, when I'm facing the socket things, I will also thread off and use async. functions to play around with. However, this RPC call function was generated by the midl tool, and the tool just generates the sync. calls...   um... is there possible to generate the async. calls for the RPC functions? or Can I cancel the RPC functions (by another thread) during the execution? Cheers, Elliott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but [this link](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/timeout-rpc-call-via-tcp-ip-help-26556272.html) suggests that [`RpcSetBindingOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with RPC_C_OPT_CALL_TIMEOUT should allow you to set the callout.

However, there's still a 20 second timeout on the first call (so the server can start).

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot :)  Even the first call still timeout as what I set into the function, and I'm using 64bit Windows 2003 Server (i.e. not only work on WinXP :D).